# answer the shell command in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, shell, jupyter-notebook

In Jupiter notebook, We can run a shell command line.

For example:

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow
```

the output

```
Uninstalling tensorflow-1.14.0:
  Would remove:
    /Users/xx/anaconda3/bin/freeze_graph
    /Users/xx/anaconda3/bin/saved_model_cli
    /Users/xx/anaconda3/bin/tensorboard
    /Users/xx/anaconda3/bin/tf_upgrade_v2
    /Users/xx/anaconda3/bin/tflite_convert
    /Users/xx/anaconda3/bin/toco
    /Users/xx/anaconda3/bin/toco_from_protos
    /Users/xx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow-1.14.0.dist-info/*
    /Users/xx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/*
Proceed (y/n)?
```

How can I input `y` to continue the excursion?

Comment: try !sudo pip uninstall tensorflow

Comment: This command will ask me to input the password.

Comment: do you have a password on your computer?

Comment: Thansk a lot, It's work for me.